# Go get path is a GOROOT, not a GOPATH error, even with env set up in Windows

Tags: go

In Windows 8, whenever I try to download a package with `go get` and `go install` I get the following error:

```
cannot download, C:\Users\MYUSER\go is a GOROOT, not a GOPATH. For more details see: 'go help gopath'
```

I had manually set up the environment variables GOPATH, GOROOT and GOTOOLDIR for both the computer and the current user to no avail

User go env

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\MYUSER\go
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
```

Administrator prompt go env

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\MYUSER\go
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
```

Is this a known issue with go get or I'm still doing something wrong with my setup? Thanks in advance

Comment: You likely have `GOROOT` files in `C:\Users\MYUSER\go` caused by setting `GOROOT` at some point. Also, don't set `GOROOT` or `GOTOOLDIR` unless you intend to change them from the defaults.

Comment: It was the former. Get should inform with a little more detail about this case, but anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out, go get checks for the file "src/cmd/go/alldocs.go" to verify that the path is goroot. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20057) about the aggressive check but it was closed in a "won't fix" fashion. At least it could use a different error message, but that's how it works as of today